# Приведение списка классов к списку T

Tags: c#, linq

Появилась проблема. Есть у меня класс `First`. Я пытаюсь написать метод на шаблоне T и при попытке вернуть List у меня выходит ошибка:

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable'

Не могу понять почему такое происходит. Ведь у Enumerable есть toList
Почему я не могу выбрать какой тип я хочу подать на выход? Или тут без явного приведения типов не обойтись?

Вот пример моего кода:

```
class Program
{
    List<First> fl = new List<First>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    public List<T> GetF<T>() where T : First
    {
        return fl.Where(a => a is T).ToList<T>();
    }
}

public class First
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ваш код - загадка. Что вы хотите сделать? оставьте просто ToList();

Comment: where T : First тут явно лишний

Comment: @pashagoroshko да я хочу выбрать все элементы из листа являющимися First в итоге да просто что бы выдать ToList(). Но почему ошибка происходит я хочу понять.

Comment: Используйте просто `ArrayList` тогда.

Comment: @Bulson спасибо кончено но я не пытаюсь уйти от этого я спросил в чём причина. Хочу докопаться до корня проблемы.

Comment: А какой смысл в данном коде, если у вас изначально коллекция нужных элементов (`List<First>`)?  Ну а так, `fl.Where(a => a is T)` выдаст вам `IEnumerable<First>`, написав просто `.ToList()` вы получите `List<First>`. Вам же нужен `List<T>`, это два совершенно разных типа. Вам тут скорей всего нужен `.Cast<T>()` после `.While()`, тогда получите элементы нужного типа, которые потом можно просто привести к листу (`.ToList()`).

Comment: List — это коллекция, список, но не лист. Лист — это орган растения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас T : First, т. е. T является First, т. е. в общем случае там может быть любой наследник First. Чуете к чему клоню? Если T : First, то в общем случае обратное неверно: First не является T. Поэтому компилятор не может сделать то что вы хотите. Вам нужно явно повысить тип:

```
return fl.Where(a => a is T).Select(a => (T)a).ToList<T>();
```

, либо, что тоже самое, только короче:

```
return fl.OfType<T>().ToList<T>();
```

Comment: как то сложно, T == First, но First != T, это как?

Comment: @pashagoroshko, я разве написал про `==`? `Является` — это не `==`. Например, любое целое число является рациональным, но в общем случае рациональное число не является целым.

Comment: Андрей большое спасибо, а почему не работает вот такой вот вариант: `return fl.Where(a => a is T) as List<T>;` ошибки нет, но возвращается null

Comment: @Андрей, потому что `IEnumerable<First>` вообще никак не является `List<T>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP но я же в IEnumerable положил List который от него унаследован.

Comment: @Андрей, а Where превратил его в IEnumerable. Но даже если бы вы написали `fl as List<T>`, то все равно бы получили null, потому что List<First> не является List<T>

Comment: @АндрейNOP Большое спасибо за разъяснение. Я в принципе понимал, что нужно тип привести, но просто ошибка меня смущала. Которая говорила что нет подходящего метода toList.

Comment: @Андрей, это да, иногда сообщения компилятора вводят в заблуждение